# Using cloudpages in SMS messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, landing-page, sms

I would like to know if it is possible to, once I add the link of a cloudpage in an SMS message, retrieve the info of the customer like to store it in a Data Extension:

- SubscriberKey
- MobileMessageTrackingID
- MessageName
- Date

Is it work as with the emails? (AMPScript speaking)

Comment: Please accept as accepted answer if I have answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass those data attributes to the CloudPage by using `CloudPagesURL` and on the Cloud Page itself, you can use an `UpsertData` to store it in a data extension.

Here are some mobile messaging variables in AMPscript: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/mobileVariables.htm

CloudPagesURL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm

UpsertData: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm